# Pixel RGB Value Identifier - TypeError: argument must be sequence of length 2

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, python-3.8

I've been having trouble with PIL and trying to get my program to print the rgb value of a pixel.

**The code**:

```
import PIL

try:
    import Image
except ImportError:
    from PIL import Image

###
    
filename = input ('Picture Filename - ')

image = PIL.Image.open(filename)

image.show()

width, height = image.size

image_rgb = image.convert('RGB')

w = 1
h = 1

a = 1
b = 2
while a < b:
    while (w <= width):
        rgb_pixel_value_1 = int(image_rgb.getpixel(w))
        rgb_pixel_value_2 = int(image_rgb.getpixel(h))
        print(rgb_pixel_value_1)
        print(rgb_pixel_value_2)
        w += 1
    if w == width and h < height:
        h += 1
    if h == height:
        a = 3
```

Intended Output:
The program should print the value of every pixel from [1, 1] to [height, width]

Actual Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "I:/Programming/Python/Useful Projects/Image Colour Space Checker/Revision 1.py", line 27, in <module>
    rgb_pixel_value_1 = int(image_rgb.getpixel(w))
  File "C:\Users\rdmor\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1367, in getpixel
    return self.im.getpixel(xy)
TypeError: argument must be sequence of length 2
```

What I've tried:
I have tried very little as there is so little about this subject on the internet and anything at all related was mildly useful at best

**There are likely other errors, however minor, that I haven't noticed yet**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When getting pixels from a specified x and y, getpixel expects a sequence with a length of two to be passed. In your code you have

```
rgb_pixel_value_1 = int(image_rgb.getpixel(w))
```

to get the rgb values from a specified position you need

```
r, g, b = image_rgb.getpixel((w, h))
```

Comment: Thank you, I have solved that issue and come across another issue saying 'IndexError: image index out of range' on that line

Comment: @RossM that means you are trying to get the values of a pixel that is outside of the image. It looks like a for loop would be best in this situation.

Comment: Ok, I'll look into it. Thank you for your time